# In primefaces some variables where erased by p:wizard

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm programming with Primefaces a I use p:wizard.

I have a problem. When I´m on step 1 I have access to all my variables, but when I change to step 2 to generate the panelGrid, the variables that were available on step 1 are now empty in the method createForm:

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="wiz">
    <p:tab id="stepone" title="Step 1">
       <p:panel>
           <h:panelGrid >
              <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [1], true)">next</h:outputLink>
           </h:panelGrid>
       </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="step2" title="Step 2">
        <p:panel>
           <h:panelGrid >
               <h:panelGrid  binding="#{ingresoBean.panelGrid}">
           </h:panelGrid>
           <h:panelGrid >
                <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [0], true);">return</h:outputLink>
           </h:panelGrid>
         </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
 </p:wizard>
```

And the bean:

```
List<Element> listElement;
private transient UIComponent panelGrid;
public IngresoBean() {
    this.initForm();
}
public UIComponent getPanelGrid() {
    if (panelGrid == null) {
        panelGrid = createForm();
         }
         return panelGrid;
    }
    .....
public void setPanelGrid(UIComponent panelGrid) {
    this.panelGrid = panelGrid;
}

public UIComponent createForm(){
    //here the listElement isnull
    for(SiacFrmdinamico campo:listElement){
        ....
    }
}
public void initForm(){
   ...
   // populate listElement
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documenation:

> To begin with create your backing bean, it’s important that the bean
>   lives across multiple requests so avoid a request scope bean. Optimal
>   scope for wizard is viewScope.

Basically, annotate your class with `@ViewScoped` and make sure your wizard is within `<f:view>` tags.